# Can I call a resize event without manually resizing in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

To make it short: I have a bug regarding Qt in combination with optirun (or similiar things). I posted it already on [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38664), but it is not solved yet. With updating to the Qt version 5.4 it occurs another bug. The working window is just in the upper left corner in the resolution 100x30. It looks a bit similar to the right picture from the bug report. But by manually resizing it, the fixed and bigger size of the rendering window can be restored. That everything looks normal again.

Is there the possibility to emit an resize event without manually resize the whole window? Currently, I tried to call the methods of the resize event manually, but this did not seem to work properly.
Has anybody another idea to solve this problem? Maybe I am not the only one with that bug or maybe someone can imagine another solution without manually resizing the window? Any help would be great.

All I want is that the start of the program creates instantly a bigger widget to render in it.

Edit (some more information):

I also tried to set a minimum size to the central widget in the UI-Designer of the QtCreator and this worked for all resolutions besides 1120x800 and at this resolution the program aborts while binding the framebuffer object. I know it's a bit strange, but that is the resolution I needed and I really don't know, why the manual resizing works, but not the initial one.

Comment: 100x30 is the default size for widgets. Is there any reason why you can't just use setGeometry() to set the window and widgets to the size you want?

Comment: It is the same like setting the minimum size to the wanted resolution. The binding of the FBO fails and causes a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that if you want to trigger a resize event, you do it using the `postEvent` mechanism. When a resize event is created, it's done using this system anyway so it conforms to what's happening under the hood. If you look [on the Qt Docs for Events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#sending-events) it has some discussion on sending and posting events, all you need then is to create a [QResizeEvent object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qresizeevent.html).

Comment: I don't know why, but calling 'postEvent' causes a segementation fault error in my program. My current solution is now to press a button to resizes the windows tot the fixed size, which is not optimal, but it works.

Comment: Could you show the code where you set up the `QResizeEvent` and the `postEvent`? I might be able to spot why it's segfaulting.

Comment: I used it like the other solution by pressing a button within the class MainWindow. And I have done the following: `QSize newSize(1120,800);`, `QSize oldSize(this->size());`, `QResizeEvent myResizeEvent(newSize,oldSize);` and `QCoreApplication::postEvent(this,&myResizeEvent);`

Comment: From the documentation for postEvent(): The event must be allocated on the heap since the post event queue will take ownership of the event and delete it once it has been posted.

Comment: @DanceIgel: you need to do `QResizeEvent *myResizeEvent = new QResizeEvent(newSize, oldSize)` instead. As Stuart Fisher says `postEvent` requires the object to be on the heap, you get your segfault as the `myResizeEvent` has gone out of scope and the event system is referencing invalid memory.